# Железобетонная буквица

Tags: css

Необходимо выделить первую букву первого и только одного в документе `<p>` внутри `<div class='layout_data'>`  вне зависимости от уровня вложенности.

```
.layout_data p:first-of-type:first-letter {
    font: 3.5em ProximaNova-Bold, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
    line-height: 42px !important; /*По высоте буквы*/
    color: #bf1238 !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin: 7px 8px 0 -2px !important;
}
```

Такой вариант работает только при такой структуре:

```
<div class='layout_data'>
       <p>Текст1</p>
       <p>Текст2</p>
    </div>
```

При такой архитектуре:

```
<div class='layout_data'>
           <p>Текст1</p>
<div>
<p>Текст2</p>
</div>

        </div>
```

Первая буква "Текста2" также выделяется.

Comment: .layout_data > p:first-of-type:first-letter

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/bxcutd1p/

Comment: Не сработает, если первым будет стоять `<p>` внутри `<div>` или все `<p>` внутри `<div>

Comment: тогда так - .layout_data:first-letter

Comment: Так тоже не пойдёт, нужна привязка именно к `<p>`, так как помимо текста в `<p>` может быть заголовок, которому присваивать этот стиль не нужно

Comment: тогда необходимо использовать javascript

Answer (score 0):

Можно поставить первую букву в отдельном тэге `h1` или создать класс для одного из `p`

Answer (score 0):

В CSS существует синтаксис [`A > B`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/child), который позволяет в элементе `A` использовать стили для элемента `B`, только когда он дочерний для элемента `A`.

```css
.layout_data > p:first-child:first-letter {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='layout_data'>
  <p>Текст1</p>
  <p>Текст2</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='layout_data'>
  <p>Текст1</p>
  <div>
    <p>Текст2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='layout_data'>
  <div>
    <p>Текст2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```